# How to get all existing groups in jcr?

Tags: java, adobe, aem, jcr

I want to fetch a list of all existing groups in CQ5 JCR. I am able to fetch a list of all existing users in the JCR using following code,

```
        UserManager userManager = jkrSession.getUserManager();
        final List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
        Iterator<Authorizable> iter = userManager.findAuthorizables(
              "jcr:primaryType", "rep:User");
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Authorizable auth = iter.next();
        if (!auth.isGroup()) {
                        users.add(auth.getID());
                }
        }
```

I haven't found any way to get a list of all existing users. Although, I can see the parent nodes /home/users and /home/groups and I can iterate over the child nodes to fetch users and groups.

I am looking for an easier way out.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question doesn't sync with your question's content.

First, the following code is really unnecessary, as you are searching for **rep:User**, and hence only users would be available in the iterator, thereby making your if check fail every time.

```
    Authorizable auth = iter.next();
    if (!auth.isGroup()) {
        users.add(auth.getID());
    }
```

Hence the while loop could be rewritten as

```
    users.add(iter.next().getID());
```

Second, if it is the list of all existing groups that you want to fetch, then you can use

```
    Iterator<Authorizable> iter = userManager.findAuthorizables(
          "jcr:primaryType", "rep:Group");
```

This would return only the groups that are present in your instance.

But, if it is both, users and groups that you want to fetch, may be you can try this.

```
    Iterator<Authorizable> iter = userManager.findAuthorizables(
          "profile/jcr:primaryType", "nt:unstructured", UserManager.SEARCH_TYPE_AUTHORIZABLE);
```

This would return all the authorizables that are present in the instance. It is not mandatory that you have to specify only **profile/jcr:primaryType** and **nt:unstructured** as the property and value. You can use the relative path to any property which would be present in all the authorizables, containing the same value if you want to list all the authorizables(in my case *profile/jcr:primaryType* caught my eye first), else the results would be filtered to those authorizables for whom the property value matches.

For further reference you can check the [docs](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/UserManager.html#findAuthorizables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29).